# Extjs grid filter in number column

Tags: extjs-grid

I have a grid with filters working fine. My issue is, if I give 1.00 in the search field. It shows the result with data 1.00, 10.00, 100.00, etc. I want only to show the result with data 1.00 only. The following is my code:

```
me.grid.store.filter(key, values[key]);
```

Here, 'key' is the column name and 'values[key]' is the text that is entered in search field. I think this filter rounds off my number.

Help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The field you are trying to filter by is apparently text. Change the field type to `'int'` of `'float`' and it should work.

Comment: I had given the field as numbercolumn with following properties.
                            col.xfilter.xtype = 'numberfield';
                            col.xfilter.fieldCls='xfilterCls';
                            col.xfilter.decimalPrecision = 5;
                            col.xfilter.hideTrigger = true;

Comment: I mean data field in the model configuration, not grid column.

Comment: It is already in float. I think, if the value is 10.00 it takes the value as 10 and if the value is 10.01 it takes the value as 10.01 because of the default javascript parseFloat behaviour.

Comment: It neglects zero after decimal point. I want to remove that behaviour of removing zero after decimal point.